# TS interface static name and [key: string]

Tags: typescript

```
interface P{
  data: {
    sub: number
    [key: string]: {
      arr: Array<number>
    }
  }
}
```

My data could be

```
data = { 
  sub: 1,
  DYNAMIC1: [1,2,3],
  DYNAMIC2: [3,4,5]
}
```

or

```
data = { 
  sub: 1,
  RANDOM1: [3],
  DYNAMIC1: [9,0,0]
}
```

My IDE throw this error message

> Property 'sub' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type '{ arr: number[]; }'.ts(2411)

How can I use the static attributes name and dynamic together

**added**

I already use `|` but still error from another code.

```
{
  data[key].map((num:number, index:number)=> ...) // key can not be `sub`. key always be the type `Array<number>`
}
```

above code throw this error message

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number | number[]'.   Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an index signature which enforces the return type for all properties to match the index signature return type. However you can fix it by using the union operator e.g.

```
interface P {
  data: {
    [key: string]: number | Array<number>;
  };
}
```

If you want to keep `sub` as defined property, you have to extend the index with the concrete type of `number` e.g.

```
interface P{
  data: {
    sub: number
    [key: string]: Array<number> | number
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add `|` but I couldn't use it. I will add to my question about it.

Comment: @zynkn That is a different error. You can not call `.map()` on a `number`. You have to type check your `data[key]` e.g. with `hasOwnProperty("map")`

Comment: yeah, I know I can't call `map()` on the type `number` I am not trying to do this. I think I need to edit my code little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) as followed:

```
type P = {
  data: {
    [key: string]: number | Array<number>;
  } & {
    sub: number
  };
}
```